# Sending file together with form data via ajax post in php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Here is what I'm trying to do.

I'm uploading a file on the form and send the data via ajax.

Here is my code:

```
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" name="addcert_form" id="addcert_form" method="post" >
       <input type='hidden' id="staffid" name="staffid" value="<?php echo $staffid; ?>" />

        <label for="certNumber"><?php echo("Certification Number"); ?></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control certNumber" id="certNumber" name="certNumber"  >

         <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom: 0px;margin-left: 15px;">
            <label for="file-upload"><?php echo('File Upload'); ?></label>
                <input type='hidden' id="file-upload-hidden" name="file-upload-hidden" />
                 <input type="file" name="file-upload" id="file-upload" accept="application/pdf">                
         </div> 
    </form>


     $(document).on('change', "#cert-upload", function() {
       var ajaxurl = generalObj.ajax_url; 
       var form = $("#addcert_form");
       var params = form.serializeArray();

       var formData = new FormData();                          
       var file_data = $('#file-upload').prop('files')[0];

       $(params).each(function (index, element) {         
         formData.append(element.name, element.value);
       });

     formData.append('file-upload', file_data);

     $.ajax({
        url: ajaxurl + "rzvy_staff_ajax.php",
        data: formData,        
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false, 
        type: 'POST',
       success: function (res) {
        if(res=="file-uploaded"){
            swal.fire(generalObj.updated, generalObj.cert-upload_changed, "success");
            //location.reload();
        }     
    }
});
  });
```

However, when I see the information, I'm only getting the file info.

I have tried doing $_POST, and $_FILES, however, I'm not getting the information from the form. How can I get all of the information from the form when I upload the file?

Thank you,
Kevin

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I found out. The data was coming over, I should have used both $_FILES and $_POST